# What is the price of silver in True Blood?

Tags: tv, vampire, true-blood

I seem to remember a line in one of the early seasons of True Blood mentioning that silver had outpaced gold on the commodities market.

Is it ever stated how much silver is actually worth?

Comment: Interestingly enough, silver *did* outpace gold in some  parts of ancient history. (Though that's not relevant to the question)

Comment: I am kinda interested in the economical impact something like that would have

Comment: In which episode, specifically, was this mentioned? We could derive an estimate! First, we find out the date that that episode took place on (within the story). Then, we simply look up the value of gold for that date. The value of silver would have had to be `>=` that value.

Answer (score 1):

No mention is made (at least in dialogue) of the relative prices of gold and silver in the True Blood fictional universe.

As far as I can tell, the sole mention of the *cost of silver* is that colloidal spray silver is freely available, but also **expensive for what it is** (e.g. a microscopic amount of silver held in a suspension of water).

> **Pam:** *Don't you want the key? Colloidal silver, in stock and overpriced at your neighborhood health food store.*

Frankly, that's entirely true in [our reality](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Concentration-%E2%9C%85Certified-Independent-Laboratories-Katharos/dp/B018T6XHN8/) as well.